# Two-Way Speakers & First Order Butterworth Crossover

Tags: impedance

I live in the Upper Hunter of NSW and my knowledge of electronics is rudimentary.

Recently I found a pair of two way bookshelf speakers. The cabinet of both speakers had been opened up and the wires removed. Also, there were no capacitors & inductors, only the drivers alone.

The speaker drivers belonging to both bookshelf cabinets appear in reasonably good condition. Further, when I tested the drivers with my multimeter I obtained clear electrical continuity and an impedance of 6 Ohms individually for the woofer and tweeter drivers belonging to both bookshelf cabinets.
It is my intention to repair the speakers if I am able. However, at this point there is something I am unclear about.

Having conducted some basic research regarding two way speakers I have decided to adopt the straightforward 1st order Butterworth crossover method. And I will make the crossover 3200Hz. Using a crossover calculator, I discovered online I will need a 8.2UF capacitor for the tweeter and a 0.30mH inductor for the woofer.

What I need to know is if I correctly wire the capacitors & inductors with both bookshelf cabinet speakers, according to the 1st order Butterworth crossover method: What will the impedance measure with a multimeter at the binding post connectors at the back of each two way speaker bookshelf cabinets?

Comment: *Impedance*...with a multimeter? Most multimeters use DC to measure resistance. If yours is one of these, you'll measure the \$ 6 \Omega \$ of the woofer plus a little extra from the wire resistance of the 0.3mH inductor. Resistance of the tweeter isn't included because of the series-connected capacitor.